# A single word for an inanimate object that is very old and held in high esteem

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective for an inanimate object that is very old and held in very high esteem?

Especially in the context of buildings for example:

The government building is ***_*__*_*** . Many people flock to visit it every year.

Antique doesn't seem to be a good choice as it doesn't always give the meaning of something being held in very high esteem.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun, or would something like "venerable" do?

Comment: I'm looing for an adjective

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: historical, historic, renowned, totemic (not exactly the best for a building), monumental. Also try a thesaurus.

Comment: On the scope of age, are you looking for something that would be considered younger than ancient? My first thought was to use the word `prestigious`, but it lacks any sense of age.

Answer (score 4):

The government building is an ***historic landmark.***

> [*landmark*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/landmark) : 2. A notable location with historical, cultural, or geographical significance

Comment: A landmark doesn't need to be very old, as required by the OP. It only needs to be notorious.

Comment: @CesarGon: I think that's why Jim proposed _historic_ landmark. While it is indeed possible for historic landmarks to be relatively new ([NASA's mission control center](http://www.nps.gov/nhl/QA.htm#1) comes to mind), they are regarded to be generally old, I think. I believe newer historic landmarks would be the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @J.R.: I agree; I didn't downvote the answer because I am aware of that. Just making a point since the OP wants a *single word*.

Answer (score 2):

If it were smaller, I might well go with an *heirloom*, but probably not for a building.  There you might may have to stick with some sort of *historical monument* or even a *national treasure*.  You might also be able to work in *heritage* there somehow, as in a *world heritage site*.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I hear a lot of the expression ***heritage structure***.

Though dictionaries generally define a ***monument*** as a commemorative, the term is also used in the cultural context for a structure of heritage value:

"• Monumental heritage of exceptional cultural value;" (UNESCO: [Historic Urban Landscape](http://portal.unesco.org/en/ev.php-URL_ID=48857&URL_DO=DO_TOPIC&URL_SECTION=201.html))

Wikipedia includes the 'heritage' sense of usage:

> [**Monument**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument)
> ... which has become important to a social group as a part of their remembrance of historic times or cultural heritage, or simply as an example of historic architecture.

Oxford Dict.

> **[monument](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/monument)** a building, structure, or site that is of historical importance or interest

I feel the example sentence sounds better with a noun instead.

> *The government building is a heritage monument. Many people flock to visit it every year.*

Answer (score 0):

I like *edifice* but it’s a noun not an adjective. You could combine with it an adjective such as *stately* -

The government building is a *stately edifice*. Many people flock to it every year.